# How to disconnect from wireless connection manually using the command line without using network manager?

Tags: wireless, command-line

I don't want to use WICD or NetWork-Manager. What should I type to disconnect ?

EDIT: This one is different from the ones above, I want to **disconnect**. Another thing, I don't want use `WICD` nor `Network-Manager`.  As a prove, the answer below is not the same as the answers provided in these questions.

Comment: Voting to re-open, however there seem to be *two* duplicates.  Have you tried both?

Comment: @seth I didnt vote to reopen. it seems the mods decided to reopen it. as for the dupes. the solution that i want is not in these questions. user Douglas below wrote what I was looking for

Comment: You can see who re-opened your question by checking the [revision history.](http://askubuntu.com/posts/276822/revisions)  Thanks for clarifying about the dupes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take the wireless interface down using the command line.

Open a Terminal window, and enter:

```
ifconfig -a
```

You will get a list of all of the network interfaces. Your wireless will likely be called `wlan0`, and you can corroborate this with the information listed, such as the `SSID`, etc.

In Terminal enter:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

You will be asked for your password, in order for this command to be run with the permissions needed. (if you don't have the permissions, you will be warned so.) This assumes `wlan0` was your wireless interface.

Enter again:

```
ifconfig -a
```

and you should see `wlan0` (or your interface) has been labelled `DOWN`.

**To reverse this, enter:**

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Comment: wow, nice and simple answer thanks for porivding the `ifconfig up`. There are some issues though, My interface is called `eth1` So its not necessarily called `wlan0`. So you might wan to update your answer to change it to be `intefaceX` or something like that.

Comment: @Suhaib, **very** unlikely for a wireless interface to named ethX, is this within a virtual machine?

Comment: @guntbert, No! I am not using virtual one. here is a proof http://i.imgur.com/F1qFna3.png