# How can I disable my internet connection from terminal?

Tags: networking, command-line

The *connect automatically* option is allowed for my wired *Wired connection 1*. Disconnecting the connection works when I do it from the panel's **Network > Disconnect** menu. But when I do that with command:

```
nmcli con down id "Wired connection 1"
```

no sooner than it disconnects, the connection is back on.

How does **Network > Disconnect** work? Could we do the same with `nmcli` without disabling the automatic connection?

Note:

1. `nmcli con down id "Wired connection 1"` works as with *automatic connection* disabled (but again that's not an option),
2. I don't want to use `sudo` (wouldn't be good to implement in a script!).

Comment: Maybe this will help. This also worked for me.
[Here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/276822/how-to-disconnect-from-wireless-connection-manually-using-the-command-line-witho

Comment: Yes that's a way.. but I don't want to to run a command with raised privilege..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following command works for me like a charm if I want to disable any internet connection from terminal:

```
nmcli networking off
```

To enable it again:

```
nmcli networking on
```

**Note**: As [commented by CPBL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434660/disable-internet-connection-from-terminal/434664#comment961012_434664), this works in Ubuntu 15.04 and later. For older versions try `nmcli nm enable false` and `nmcli nm enable true`.

---

Another way very close to your quest is to use:

```
nmcli dev disconnect iface eth0
```

To enable eth0 again you need to type:

```
nmcli -p con up id "<connection name>" iface eth0
```

Example for connection named "Wired connection 1":

```
nmcli -p con up id "Wired connection 1" iface eth0
```

Change `eth0` to your wired interface name. This will prevent any further connections without user/manual intervention as `man nmci` says:

```
disconnect iface <iface> [--nowait] [--timeout <timeout>]
           Disconnect a device and prevent the device from automatically
           activating further connections without user/manual intervention.

           Available options are:
                --nowait     – exit immediately without waiting for
                command completion

                --timeout    – how long to wait for command completion
                (default is 10 s)
```

Please read `man nmcli` for more info.

Comment: `nmcli nm enable false` is very different from what _Network -> Disconnect_ option does.. the latter just disables the _specified connection_ (no elevated privileges required), but the former disables _networking_!

Comment: @rusty well, by disabling networking, you are sure that your internet connection is disabled. If this is not what you asked, please clarify your question.

Comment: I'm looking to disable a particular connection but not the network itself..

Comment: @rusty Pease see my new edits.

Comment: ..`nmcli dev disconnect iface eth0` is the one; it disconnects the active connection (say "Wired connection 1") configured to use the device `eth0`.. and following that I can use `nmcli con up id "Wired connection 2"` to connect with it's another configuration.. (with `nmcli nm enable false` that would take `nmcli nm enable true && nmcli con up id "Wired connection 2"`)

Comment: Regarding @Radu's original response, it no longer works in Ubuntu 15.04. Instead  `nmcli networking off` is the new way to shut down all networking until manually restarted, and it does not require sudo.

Comment: [To get](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432251/209677) the wired interfaces: `ip -o link show | awk -F': ' '{if ($2 ~ /en/) print $2}'`