# How can I restart my Wi-Fi connection from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, wireless

Occasionally, my Wi-Fi connection does no longer work for various reasons. Disabling and re-enabling Wi-Fi through the graphical interface of the network indicator does not resolve the problems in these cases.

How can I completely restart my Wi-Fi connection from the command-line without having to restart my machine (which fixes these problems)?

Comment: Have a look at this on stack exchange [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90778/how-to-bring-up-a-wi-fi-interface-from-a-command-line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disconnect from wireless connection manually using the command line without using network manager?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276822/how-to-disconnect-from-wireless-connection-manually-using-the-command-line-witho)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`nmcli` is very useful command-line utility for interacting with Network Manager. Use this command in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
nmcli radio wifi off && sleep 5 && nmcli radio wifi on
```

For versions prior to 15.10 ( i.e. before transition to `systemd` ) the command would be slightly different:

```
nmcli nm wifi off && sleep 5 && nmcli nm wifi on
```

Good thing about it - this doesn't require root powers.

Restarting network manager itself is a good idea as well.

For 16.04 LTS:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

and for 14.04 LTS:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And if we really wanted to, we could even automate it with a script that will restart your wifi.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# replace wlan0 with your device name
# as given by ip addr or ifconfig
while true 
do
    # keep checking if we have ip address    
    wifi_info=$(ip -4 -o addr  show wlan0 )
    while [ -n "$wifi_info" ];
    do
       wifi_info=$(ip -4 -o addr  show wlan0 )
       sleep 0.25
    done

    # We get here only if IP address is lost
    # which means we're off-line
    # restart wifi 
    nmcli radio wifi off && sleep 5 && nmcli radio wifi on
done
```

Comment: `.service` is implied, so can be omitted `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Comment: @Zanna TIL... I have been typing `.service` this whole time.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Thanks, excellent. Why are there 2 different commands?

Comment: @TechLord Basically, it's because since the 15.04 version, Ubuntu has switched to `systemd` init system - the stuff that actually brings up basic services and daemons when you boot. The problem is that unlike older stuff, `systemd` tries to not just *start* stuff, but also *manage*  the stuff.  This lead to `nmcli` being rewritten to match with `systemd`. At least this is my understanding.

Answer (score 11):

Two alternatives I'm thinking about follows,

**First alternative**, bring down/up the interface

```
ifconfig wlan0 down ## assumes your wlan is named wlan0
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

**Second alternative**, restart the entire network-manager. This assumes you have network-manager installed. If not, install it with the following cmd in your terminal `sudo apt-get install network-manager`.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 LTS  you can use the `systemd` feature:

```
 systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `ifdown` + interface name to disable network

> ifdown IFACE

Use `ifup` + interface name to enable it

> ifup IFACE

Replace `IFACE` with your device name as given by `ifconfig`