# Why the wireless network is no longer listed?

Tags: wireless

I've searched for answers but its seems there's no universal solutions.
I've run the script form [wireless info gathering script website](http://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info#wireless-info).

And here's the wireless info it generates[wireless info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23821128/).
Many thank to anyone who can take a look at it and help.
Thank you !

Comment: Did you have to follow instructions from some site to get it working originally?

Comment: Yes， I was trying to fix another problem and followed some instructions online and ended up with this..

Answer (score 1):

You should update your Ubuntu install to a supported kernel with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

This will install the 4.4 kernel and it will support your wifi

Comment: Maybe the firmware is also needed, but I did not check what is in the `trusty` repo.

Comment: @Pilot6 trusty has 8000C-13 in the linux-firmware package

Comment: If it is in `updates`, then Op will need to update the system first. And it depends on which pint release is installed.

Answer (score -2):

Disable Wifi and Enable Wifi again.
If you prefer command line, use following.

```
nmcli radio wifi off && sleep 5 && nmcli radio wifi on
```

This command will be restart wifi.

If you have issues with restarting Wifi and Network Manager, you can try following answer https://askubuntu.com/a/811738/640587.

Comment: I tried this but it seems it does not work..